# I am learning Python and I believe I might have a problem with the .split function in my code

Tags: python

I get this error when I type view

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chills\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\mini projects\password manager.py", line 24, in <module>        
    view()
  File "c:\Users\chills\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\mini projects\password manager.py", line 7, in view
    user, passw = (data.split("|"))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

**Code:**

```
master_pwd = input("What is your master password?")

def view():
    with open("passwords.txt", "r") as f:
     for line in f.readlines():
        data = line.rstrip()
        user, passw = (data.split("|"))
    print(f"User:", {user}, ", Password:", {passw})

def add():
    name = input("Account Name: ")
    pwd = input(" Password: ")

    with open("passwords.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(name + "|" + pwd + "\n")


while True:
    mode = input(" Would you like to add a new password or view exsisting ones (view, add) press q to quit? ").lower()
    if mode == "q":
        break

    if mode == "view":
        view()
    elif mode == "add":
        add()
    else:
        print("invalid mode.")
        continue

quit()
```

I tried messing around with what is inside the .split function. But I have had problems with splitting a function into sub functions before. I thought it could have been something with the print function trying to print the two sub functions, with no success.

Comment: The line in the error message is not the same as the line in the code you posted. You can't use an empty string as the delimiter, but `split("|")` should be fine.

Comment: The `print()` line in `view()` should be inside the `for` loop. The way you've written it, you'll only print the last user.

Comment: BTW, your file format will have a problem if the password contains the `|` character.

Comment: Did you try to print your `data`?

Comment: You may consider using `csv` or `json` to read and write the file, this way you don't have to worry about the separator appearing in either username or password.

Comment: Thank you Barmar I have fixed the error to display the right error I am getting. To be honest tobias_k I am not sure what csv or json is? I feel ultimately when I learn about them they should make things easier for me in the long run. My ultimate goal is to write a python program that can be interacted through my website or as a discord bot that they can log in and shop in my Dnd world for basic things, work or go on side quests all in the name of learning python and making something cool

Comment: @chillsbanex Both [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) are standards for converting complex data to strings (and back), for storing them in files or sending them over the web. Python has built-in modules [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) that make working with this kind of data very easy. If you didn't know those yet, learning about them will _definitely_ make things easier for you, in this project and many more to come.